# How do I tell Maxima to use more memory?

Tags: maxima

I am doing some symbolic calculation with Maxima, but I encounter the error `Heap exausted`, which I think it means that Maxima uses too much memory (over about 1 Gb). How do I tell Maxima to use more memory?

I use the most recent CentOS on a machine with 32 Gb memory.

**EDIT** Here is the code I am using

```
load("ctensor");
ct_coordsys(kerr_newman);
rho(r,theta):=r^2+a^2*cos(theta);
delta(r):=r^2-2*m*r+a^2;
lg:matrix([-(1-2*m*r/rho(r,theta)),0,0,-2*a^2*m*r*sin(theta)^2/rho(r,theta)],[0,rho(r,theta)/delta(r),0,0],[0,0,rho(r,theta),0],[-2*a^2*m*r*sin(theta)^2/rho(r,theta),0,0,sin(theta)^2*(r^2+a^2+2*a^2*m*r*sin(theta)^2/rho(r,theta))]);
lriemann(true);
uriemann(true);
rinvariant();
```

the code stops while evaluating `uriemann(true);`.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. Some investigation shows that `ratsimp` (called by `uriemann`) is processing bigger and bigger expressions. My advice at this point is to try `trace(ratsimp)` and then call `uriemann`. Do you see the expressions you would expect in the calls to `ratsimp`? Since this has to do with `ctensor`, try posting a message to maxima-discuss@lists.sourceforge.net to ask for further advice about it -- I don't know about the tensor libraries.

Answer (score 1):

"Heap exhausted" usually means some operation (e.g. factoring, simplification of rational expressions or expressions containing radicals, etc) is causing the creation of larger and larger expressions. Increasing the memory allocation rarely resolves such problems -- usually what happens is that it just runs longer and then eventually runs out of memory again.

A couple of things to try. (1) What Lisp implementation is Maxima compiled with? You can see that via `build_info();` GCL (GNU Common Lisp) uses memory less efficiently than other Lisp implementations, so you could try building Maxima with SBCL for example. Rebuilding Maxima on typical Linux distributions is pretty straightforward. I'll give more details if you want to go down that road.

(2) What, exactly, are you trying to do? Can you post the inputs which you gave which led to the memory error? Maybe we can reorganize things or try some different operations in order to prevent huge expressions in the first place.